# How did Red Skull know that the Tesseract was from Odin's treasure?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-first-avenger

In Captain America, Schmidt states that the Tesseract was an Asgardian artifact, indeed one that belonged to Odin himself.

> **Tower Keeper:** *What you seek is just a legend.*
>
> **Johann Schmidt:** *Then why make such an effort to conceal it? **The Tesseract was the jewel of Odin's treasure room.** Not something one
>   buries. But I think it is close, yes?*

How did he know this?

Comment: What do you mean? Where did Red Skull say that?

Comment: In the comics, the film, somewhere else?

Comment: @Edlothiad - Almost certainly from Captain America: TFA

Comment: @Valorum, *almost*

Comment: Presumably legend.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - That was my thought. We know that the Asgardians were making themselves into gods and spreading legends of themselves among the primitive peoples of Earth

Answer (score 6):

Johan Schmidt pushes the boundaries of science. Although supported by better scientific minds, he is very much on the fringe of what's possible with current (1940's) science.

The Tesseract has been hidden incredibly well. That castle is an old building that has clearly been guarded (and forgotten by others) for a long time.
The tower keeper himself seems distraught at the death of his family and loved ones, **yet he does not kneel to Schmidt** even after learning of their deaths. This means that he is devoted to his duty as a guardian, and considers hiding the Tesseract as his life's purpose. This further proves how diligently the Tesseract has been hidden.

Schmidt appearing in the castle already proves that he did his homework. This was not a trivial location to have a look for the Tesseract. It stands to reason that Schmidt would know everything **about** the Tesseract before knowing its **hidden location**. General knowledge about the Tesseract would be comparatively easier to find than the actual Tesseract.

Also look at the scene where Schmidt first activates the machine; and then very confidently pushes the machine over its safe limits, without any idea as to what will happen and a strong suggestion from the scientist (who built the machine) to not do so. Schmidt, while a scientist at heart, is driven by his **belief** that this machine will do what he wants it to do, and he completely foregoes any safety precautions or even measured expectations.

So the answer to your question can be distilled from the things I've mentioned.

- Schmidt has been searching for the Tesseract for a long time.
- Due to how well it has been hidden, Schmidt will have had to browse **many** pieces of information pertaining to the Tesseract.
- Schmidt does not need to **know** that the Tesseract was Odin's; he just needs to **believe** that it was. Schmidt has proven himself to be driven by his goals, not by what is currently in front of him.

Or, to condense this into a shorter answer: **He had become an expert on Tesseract knowledge; because he needed to locate it at all costs.**

Comment: I think the OP is saying how did Schmidt know the Tesseract and Asgard were real and not legend.

Comment: @aminabzz The answer addresses that Schmidt doesn't need to _know_ it to be true, he only needs to _believe_ it to be true in order to pursue it.

Answer (score 1):

Schmidt spent his time studying historical documents and artifacts in order to ascertain more information about where they came from, where they were and how to use them.  In the Marvel universe, these artifacts are real as well as the origins.  There are ruins and documents from Asgard as well as folk tales that tell of the mighty artifacts of the Asguardians.  Thus it is simple to say that in his investigations he came across evidence of the Tesseract and where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

As Thor and Odin and most Asgard was in norse mythology.

So, Tesseract was a real jewel in Odin's room (not an Infinity Stone).
Marvel just bended it as a Infinity Stone.

So, Schmidt must have read it somewhere in that norse mythology.